# Merge changes of copied repository without true common ancestor in git

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a project, DemoA that was built off of a git repository, Project1.

Unfortunately, DemoA started as simply a copy of the files from Project1, before itself turning into an actual long-term project. I would now like to make Project1 a submodule of DemoA, but - more importantly - want to merge in the changes done on the code derived from Project1, in DemoA.

I have done a subtree split on DemoA to create a branch P1, which has all the changes done to the Project1 codebase in DemoA.

I have also managed to add in the changes to Project1 made to DemoA before it was instantiated as a repository.

```
Project1
A - B - C - D                     - E
Demo1/P1
    (untracked changes) F - G - H - I

where the files in E are identical to F
```

What I want:

```
Project 1
A - B - C - D - E - G - H - I
```

Obviously the hashes for E and F are different, so when I added Demo1/P1 as a remote to Project1 and tried to merge, it complained about no common ancestor.

I have tried [using format-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217452/in-git-how-do-i-create-a-single-patch-for-the-last-2-revisions), but git am has complained

> error: file.xyz: already exists in index

and I was trying to [rebase onto a different branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973268/replay-the-last-n-git-commits-on-a-different-branch/973403#973403), doing:

```
git rebase -s recursive -X subtree=project1dir --onto (E-hash) (F-hash) emptybranch
```

but I clearly don't understand what that is actually doing, as it didn't seem to actually *do* anything.

Is there a clean way to do this? I don't mind some manualness to the process, but I would like to preserve the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all moderately difficult (actual difficulty level varies depending on circumstances and your familiarity with Git).

If the files in `E` and `F` are truly identical, the (or an) easy way to do this would be to put in a graft (with `git replace` or the grafts file) so that Git pretends that `G`'s parent commit is commit `E`.  That is, you have:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master

F-------------G--H--I   <-- refs/remotes/rem/P1
```

and `git diff master rem/P1~4` produces no output at all (`master` names commit `E`, `rem/P1~4` names commit `F`, and the two trees for `E` and `F` match exactly).

You *wish*, at least as an intermediate product perhaps, that you had this:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
F             G--H--I   <-- refs/remotes/rem/P1
```

That is, you'd like Git to pretend, at least for some purposes and some period of time, that commit `G` has commit `E` as its parent.

#### Using `git replace` to emulate the old horrible-hack grafts

Git grafts do precisely that: they tell Git to *pretend* that the parent(s) of some commit is some other commit(s).  But these have been deprecated in favor of the more generic [`git replace`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html).  You can use `git replace` to make a new commit `G'` that resembles (but supersedes, at least, for most Git commands) `G`, with the one difference being that `G'` has `E` as its parent.

You can then use `git filter-branch` to re-copy commits in the repository so that this replacement becomes real and permanent, rather than just a copy.  You will, of course, get new commit hashes for the new commits (`G'` can keep its hash but you must get a new `H'` and `I'`).  See [this answer by Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3811028/1256452), and then [How do git grafts and replace differ? (Are grafts now deprecated?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6800692/1256452), where VonC links to Jakub's answers.

(Git grafts do still work, and you can just put the hash for commits `G` and `E` into `.git/info/grafts`: `echo $(git rev-parse rem/P1~3) $(git rev-parse master) > .git/info/grafts`, for instance.  But they *are* a horrible hack and if you do this sort of trick it's best to just run your filter-branch immediately afterward, as Jakub notes.)

#### Using `git rebase`

You can also use `git rebase --onto`, as you were attempting, but you must start this rebase using an existing (ordinary, local) branch name (I'm not sure where `emptybranch` came from here) that points to commit `I`.  I think maybe the step you are missing might be making this regular ordinary local branch name:

```
git checkout -b rewrite rem/P1
```

for instance, assuming the name `rem/P1` resolves to commit `I`.  Or `git checkout -b rewrite <hash-of-I>`, if you have that hash in front of you for easy cut/paste.  At that point you will have this:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master

F-------------G--H--I   <-- HEAD -> rewrite, rem/P1
```

That is, you're now on this new `rewrite` branch, which points to commit `I`.  Now you can `git rebase --onto master HEAD~3` to copy the most recent 3 commits on the current branch—`G`, `H`, and `I`.  The copies will be `G'`, `H'`, and `I'`, with the parent of `G'` being `E`—the commit to which `master` points—and the parent of `H'` being `G'` and so on:

```
              G'-H'-I'   <-- HEAD -> rewrite
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master

F-------------G--H--I   <-- rem/P1
```

Now you can delete the remote and its remote-tracking branch since you have the commit chain you want.  You can also fast-forward `master` to point to commit `I'` at any time, if that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had time to try this; but it looks like it may solve my issues! I will try in the near future and accept if it works.